# Livewire 3 render component in Route handler

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I want to render two *Livewire* components conditionally on the same route:

```php
Route::get('/endpoint', function() {
  if (condition) {
    return ???; // to render ComponentA
  }

  return ???; // to render ComponentB
});
```

I read the docs and it shows an example where you can render `Route::get('/endpoint', Component::class);`, but I have a different use case.

I tried to use `Blade::render()` and `Blade::renderComponent()` but I did not succeed.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have each return a view that has a livewire component in it?

Comment: I tried that but for some reason it does not work? I think the lifecycle hooks are running differently since I got some issues referring to some properties that should be mounted

Comment: Juste a comment, Blade Render  works only for View/Component (normal components created with make:component ) and would not work for your livewire component which extends Livewire/Component.

Answer (score 0):

Since a Livewire component extends *Livewire\Component* which uses the *HandlesPageComponents* trait which in turn contains the *__invoke()* method, everything comes back to the system used by [Single Action Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#single-action-controllers) and therefore it is possible to conditionally use different Livewire component classes in the *Route()* method:

```php
Route::get('/endpoint', $condition ? \App\Livewire\ComponentA::class : \App\Livewire\ComponentB::class);
```

Comment: This is okay if a ternary suffices, but if I need a function what should I do? Moreover, having access to Request and other utilities is what I'm building the condition on

Comment: Now I think this is a  [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), probably the solution that you are asking is not the better way to solve your main problem. Perhaps explaining better why you want to render conditionally a component from a route can help

Comment: I agree that I might not be choosing the best approach, but I'm asking for a somewhat reasonable feature. Maybe I missed something in the docs, or I overlooked something. For example, you can render a blade component using `Blade::render`, and my question is how can I achieve that with Livewire

Comment: You can't simply "render" a Livewire view because it's associated with a piece of javascript code that interacts with the backend (the class associated to the view), all of which is set up by the process mentioned in my answer. Explain better what you really want to achieve so that someone can be of help